# Grab the label of each item of an enumerate list

Tags: macros, enumerate

I have a macro called `\addsol` that appends solutions for given exercises to a fixed `\solutions` macro, in order to list the solution of the exercises at the end of the document.

I wish to add to it an automatic mechanism such that each solution is preceded by it's label in the `enumerate` block.

Ideally, it would be great if there exists some instruction that imitates the label used in the enumerate list, whether it its A, B, C or 1) 2) 3) without having to reconfigure the command to each case.
As this seems to me difficult to obtain, I tried to use the `enumi` counter, as shown in the MWE below, but the output doesn't give the number of each question, instead, it gives the final value of `enumi`.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\equal}{=}

\newcommand{\addsol}[1]{%
  \ifdefined\solutions
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\solutions\expandafter{\solutions,\ $\Alph{enumi}\equal$ #1}%
  \else
    \gdef\solutions{\textbf{Solutions:} $\Alph{enumi}\equal$ #1}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=$\Alph*\equal$]
    \item $3 + 5$ \addsol{$8$}
    \item $4 \times 6$ \addsol{$24$}
    \item $54 \div 9$ \addsol{$6$}
\end{enumerate}

% Print the contents of solutions

\solutions

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the preceding exemple :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your task can be simply solved by TeX primitives:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\eaddto#1#2{\expandafter\addto\expanded{\noexpand#1{#2}}}
\newcount\exenum
\def\excercises{\exenum=`A \def\solutions{\par {\bf Solutions:} }}
\def\exe#1#2{\par $\char\exenum=#1$
   \addto\solutions{\sol{#2}}\eaddto\solutions{{\the\exenum}}
   \global\advance\exenum by1
}
\def\sol#1#2{\ifnum#2=`A \else, \fi$\char#2=#1$}
\def\solutions{\par Solutions:}

\begin{document}

\excercises
\exe{3 + 5}{8}
\exe{4 \times 6}{24}
\exe{54 \div 9}{6}

% Print the contents of solutions

\solutions

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as shown in the egreg's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `enumerate`, but `itemize`, your own counter and a simpler input syntax.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addsol}[1]{%
  \ifdefined\solutions
    \xdef\solutions{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\solutions},
      \ $\Alph{exe}=#1$%
    }%
  \else
    \xdef\solutions{\unexpanded{\textbf{Solutions:} }$\Alph{exe}=#1$}%
  \fi
}

\newcounter{exe}
\newenvironment{exercises}
 {%
   \begin{itemize}[label=]
   \setcounter{exe}{0}%
   \global\let\solutions\undefined
 }
 {\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\exe}[2]{% #1 = exercise, #2 = solution
  \item\stepcounter{exe}$\Alph{exe}=#1$\addsol{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
\exe{3 + 5}{8}
\exe{4 \times 6}{24}
\exe{54 \div 9}{6}
\end{exercises}

% Print the contents of solutions

\solutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

An `expl3` implementation

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcounter{exe}
\seq_new:N \g_ladi_solutions_seq
\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercises}{}
 {
  \begin{itemize}[label=]
  \setcounter{exe}{0}
  \seq_gclear:N \g_ladi_solutions_seq
 }
 {\end{itemize}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\exe}{mm}
 {
  \item\stepcounter{exe}$\Alph{exe}=#1$
  \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_ladi_solutions_seq { $\Alph{exe}=#2$ }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\solutions}{}
 {
  \par\textbf{Solutions:~}
  \seq_use:Nn \g_ladi_solutions_seq { ,~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercises}
\exe{3 + 5}{8}
\exe{4 \times 6}{24}
\exe{54 \div 9}{6}
\end{exercises}

% Print the contents of solutions

\solutions

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be addressed by using LaTeX3. Here is my idea, by `\addsol` you can put data to a sequence and then pop the data by `\solutions`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels,inline]{enumitem}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_solutions_seq
\tl_new:N \l_answer_tl
\NewDocumentCommand{ \addsol }{ m }{ \seq_gput_right:Nn \l_solutions_seq {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\solutions}{ }
  { \textbf{Solutions:}\c_space_tl
    \begin{enumerate}[resume*,start=1]
      \bool_do_until:nn
        { \seq_if_empty_p:N \l_solutions_seq }
        { \seq_gpop_left:NN \l_solutions_seq \l_answer_tl \item $\l_answer_tl$ }
    \end{enumerate}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\equal}{=}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=$\Alph*\equal$]
  \item $3 + 5$ \addsol{8}
  \item $4 \times 6$ \addsol{24}
  \item $54 \div 9$ \addsol{6}
\end{enumerate}

\solutions

\end{document}
```

[image]
However, the `enumerate` environment in the 10/14 lines can not be replaced by `enumerate*` since otherwise an error will be raised.

Comment: I’m afraid that I’m not familiar with the expl syntax, and was hoping for a solution with the usual plain Latex commands. But if there is no other solution for this, I will dig into it, so thank you for this proposition!

Comment: This solution could benefit from displaying the solution in-line, rather than a separate list. Also, what happens if you don't specify a solution to an exercise/problem? The solutions will print things incorrectly as it assumes you'll provide a solution for each exercise/problem.